# From Windows XP to Lubuntu 12.04 LTS: was Windows graphically best detailed?

Tags: windows, lubuntu, display

I switched from Windows XP to Lubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Pretty cool: already loving XFCE.

Anyway: I got to say that it looks like Linux is graphically less detailed.
I mean, I can clearly see a lot of pixels. 
Chrome icon, for instance, it's like a pixel armada.

So, question is: am I missing something? Is there anything I can do about?

I'm sorry, cause I know this is just a dumb, lame question.

Anyway, Linux rocks. Finally managed to come back surfing the web: instantly!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a remark: Lubuntu uses LXDE, not XFCE... XFCE is used in Xubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Graphics resolution, icon design, windows decoration, all are configurable with Openbox the default LXDE windows manager. Desktop design really only is a matter of your own preferences (e.g. you can still run Windows 7 with the look and feel of Windows NT).

You may find a theme which suits your taste better here:

- [Box Look](http://box-look.org/) themes for Openbox

Also see

- [Lubuntu/Theming](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Theming)
- [Lubuntu Artwork](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/Artwork)

Of course you can always start to contribute by developing your own theme.